# Camera to follow path of curve starting from exactly where it is currently

Tags: camera, bezier-curves, constraints, path

I need my camera to follow the path of a circle curve. However whenever I do this it creates an offset because of the cameras location as I understand it. When I go to reset the cameras location it is now not in the exact position that it started in. So I want my camera to circle around an object, but the camera needs to start in the exact position that it is in now.

Tl;DR Need camera to follow a path starting from the exact position it is in now.

sorry if that didn't make sense, please ask any questions for clarification :) I would greatly appreciate any help anyone has to offer!

Comment: Use an Empty to follow the path and parent the camera to the Empty with "Keep Transormation" (CTL-P)  Note - you won't have to worry about the Empty's path-following axis.  You can also animate the camera independently to reposition it's angle and location.as it travels.

Comment: Worked a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(Community Wiki answer from Edgel3D’s comment from 2019)

Use an Empty to follow the path and parent the camera to the Empty with "Keep Transormation" (CTL-P) Note - you won't have to worry about the Empty's path-following axis. You can also animate the camera independently to reposition it's angle and location.as it travels.